# Getting div to scroll to the bottom properly after appending an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chat interface with a div where new messages are appended after coming through a websocket.  The code looks like this:

```
var msg = '<div class="msg-text">' + data.msg_text + '</div>';
$(msg).appendTo($(".msg-box")).height();
$(".msg-box").scrollTop($(".msg-box")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Where "data" is a json object that is passed to the function.  This works great for plain text.  However, when the incoming msg has images in it, the interface doesn't properly scroll all the way to the bottom.  It only scrolls 50px (which is the height of the user chat avatar.  It doesn't scroll the entire height of the image (which is usually a 200 px thumbnail.

Here is what the appended code block might actually look like:

```
<div class='image-links'><a href='/uploads/pod_attachment/attachment/391/chat_IMG_5523-1.JPG' title='IMG_5523-1.JPG'><img src='/uploads/pod_attachment/attachment/391/thumb_IMG_5523-1.JPG'></a></div>
```

I've tried getting the height of the element I am adding, but it just returns 50px even when the element is bigger.

I have also tried:

```
var msg_box = document.getElementById("msg-box");
msg_box.scrollTop = msg_box.scrollHeight;
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the image not being fully loaded into the DOM when the scroll function is executed.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: maybe a load callback could help you? http://jsfiddle.net/zuyou0r6/

Comment: that didn't work.  the on load event never fires for the element

Comment: hod do u append the images?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Have you tried [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)? Also, images are inline elements by default. Try setting them to block.

Comment: nope.  none of this is working.